# rethinkdb google-compute-engine disconnects

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine, rethinkdb

Hi I run a rethinkdb setup on an google-compute-engine instance.

I use mostly change feeds (socket connections) to the db and connect to these from my local computer or apps.

to do this I use the npm packages rethinkdb-websocket-server and client.

It's working fine although I'm experiencing disconnects of the connections.
It's working for about 10 minutes then the connection drops and starts again..

I haven't noticed anything special on the google-compute-engine instance other than some botnet's trying to get in, I saw those in the serial console.
Could that be causing the disconnects, and in that case how do I prevent this?

it's working fine if I run the setup on my localhost instead, then there is no disconnect at all.

The rethinkdb log doesn't say anything about any issues.

Anyone that has an idea of what could be causing anything like this, I don't even know where to start looking so any suggestions is appreciated.